# How to change the payment method step title in Magento 2?

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.2.6

I would like to change the **payment method** heading in Magento 2.

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't able to find out the file where to edit this title.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to just override en_US.csv file into your theme i18n folder.

> app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/i18n/en_US.csv

2. Change as per your need in **en_US.csv**.

> Payment | As per Need

After run `setup:upgrade`

**It's work like charm**

Comment: Thanks. We are translating the site to the Swedish Language. As per your suggestion, I have overridden the file sv_SE.csv (instead of en_US.csv) but still the same title displays. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you clear var/cache and generated files and run setup:upgrade

Comment: I have got it works. The thing is we are using Mageplaza language pack and I have updated the text there to the corresponding module. Thanks again for your information.